# Reach host port from container when userland proxy is disabled

Tags: docker

I have a container in a bridged network. It can reach the host without problem, and connect to every port on the host EXCEPT for ports that were published by other containers.

I have the userland proxy disabled, so I think it might have something to do with how docker sets up the iptable rules.

Is there a simple way to allow the container to reach ports published by other containers (running in different bridged networks)?

I would like to avoid putting both containers in the same network, or switching to host-networking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem.

I have two Docker bridged networks defined:

```
eecf335e7600   net1                   bridge    local
5c7ca74637b0   net2                   bridge    local
```

I start container `c1` in network `net1`, publishing container port `8080` to host port `8081`:

```
$ docker run -d --rm --net net1 -p 8081:8080 --name c1 \
  --add-host host.docker.local:host-gateway  alpinelinux/darkhttpd
```

I start container `c2` in network `net2`, publishing container port `8080` to host port `8082`:

```
$ docker run -d --rm --net net2 -p 8082:8080 --name c2 \
  --add-host host.docker.local:host-gateway  alpinelinux/darkhttpd
```

Now from within container `c1` I can access the web service in container `c2` by accessing host port `8082`:

```
$ docker exec c1 wget -O- http://host.docker.local:8082
Connecting to host.docker.local:8082 (172.17.0.1:8082)
writing to stdout
-                    100% |********************************|   191  0:00:00 ETA
written to stdout
<html>
<head>
...
```

And from container `c2` I can access the web service in container `c1` by accessing host port `8081`:

```
$ docker exec c2 wget -O- http://host.docker.local:8081
Connecting to host.docker.local:8081 (172.17.0.1:8081)
writing to stdout
-                    100% |********************************|   191  0:00:00 ETA
written to stdout
<html>
<head>
...
```

It all seems to work as advertised. If you get different results repeating the same set of steps, the first thing I would check is to see if you have  firewall rules on your host that could be interfering with the traffic.

**Update**

As expected, the behavior is the same if I just pick a host address rather than using the `--add-host` option.  E.g., if I have:

```
$ ip -o addr |grep -o '.*inet [^ ]*'
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8
2: eth0    inet 192.168.123.106/24
4: docker_gwbridge    inet 172.23.0.1/16
8: br-70f125dc5b7d    inet 192.168.208.1/20
15: br-a87cc1462629    inet 172.29.0.1/16
18: docker0    inet 172.17.0.1/16
35: br-eecf335e7600    inet 172.18.0.1/16
36: br-5c7ca74637b0    inet 172.19.0.1/16
```

Then these all work:

```
$ docker exec c2 wget -O- 192.168.123.106:8081 | head -3
Connecting to 192.168.123.106:8081 (192.168.123.106:8081)
writing to stdout
-                    100% |********************************|   191  0:00:00 ETA
written to stdout
<html>
<head>
 <title>/</title>
$ docker exec c2 wget -O- 172.29.0.1:8081 | head -3
Connecting to 172.29.0.1:8081 (172.29.0.1:8081)
writing to stdout
-                    100% |********************************|   191  0:00:00 ETA
written to stdout
<html>
<head>
 <title>/</title>
$ docker exec c2 wget -O- 172.18.0.1:8081 | head -3
Connecting to 172.18.0.1:8081 (172.18.0.1:8081)
writing to stdout
-                    100% |********************************|   191  0:00:00 ETA
written to stdout
<html>
<head>
 <title>/</title>
```

Etc.

> I did not mention it in the question, because I was pretty sure I already had this problem before I disabled it...

That's a pretty substantial configuration change from the default :).

If I disable the userland proxy, it all stops working.

[This article](https://www.ipspace.net/kb/DockerSvc/40-userland-proxy.html) may be of interest:

> In the previous section we identified two scenarios where Docker cannot use iptables NAT rules to map a published port to a container service:
>
> - When a container connected to another Docker network tries to reach the service (Docker is blocking direct communication between Docker networks);
> - When a local process tries to reach the service through loopback interface.
>
> In both cases, Docker uses a userland (Linux process) TCP or UDP proxy. You can easily identify the proxy with netstat command after starting a container with a published port (we'll yet again use our standard Flask application):

Comment: That's strange! I should have mentioned that my docker has the usermode-proxy disabled in daemon.json. I did not mention it in the question, because I was pretty sure I already had this problem before I disabled it, so it seemed irrelevant. Another difference is that you use "--add-host host.docker.local:host-gateway" and I just use the gateway IP without adding any host. I'm not sure if that matters?

Comment: By the way, in your example code you are starting both in net1

Comment: That's just a typo. Good catch, I'll fix it.

Comment: "Another difference is that you use "--add-host host.docker.local:host-gateway" and I just use the gateway IP" That shouldn't matter; it just resolves to a reasonable host address.

Comment: Pretty sure it's because you've disabled the userland proxy.